# Alternative to deepcopy in python

Tags: python, dictionary, copy, deep-copy

In a project we have to do for school, we got an assignment to write an implementation for the floyd-warshall algorithm.
One of the restrictions was, that we could not use import statements. 
I had not read this and write my algorithm, using deepcopy. Now I am searching for a way to make my own sort of "copy" function.

The thing I want to copy is a dictionary of 2 dictionaries

```
{"a": {...}, "b": {...}}
```

Is this possible? thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict comprehension with `copy` method of dictionary :

```
d={"a": {...}, "b": {...}}

new={i:j.copy() for i,j in d.items()}
```

Demo :

```
>>> d ={1: {1: 5}, 2: {2: 2}, 3: {3: 9}}
>>> l ={i:j.copy() for i,j in d.items()}
>>> l[1][1]=0
>>> l
{1: {1: 0}, 2: {2: 2}, 3: {3: 9}}
>>> d
{1: {1: 5}, 2: {2: 2}, 3: {3: 9}}
```